# clearInterval on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script where random keywords appear at a timed interval. What I'd like is for them to stop appearing after one is clicked on.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function generate() {
$("[id*='keyword']").each(function(){
$(this).removeClass("show");
})
var number= Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1
$("#keyword"+number).addClass("show");
}
    
$(function(){
setInterval(generate, 4000);
})
    
$("[id*='keyword']").click(function() {
clearInterval(generate);
});
div[id*='keyword']{
background: #aaa;
position: absolute;
left: -200px;
opacity: 0;
width:200px;
line-height: 60px;
text-align: center;
color: white;
height: 60px;
-webkit-transition: 1s all ease;
transition: 1s all ease;
}
div[id*='keyword'].show{
left: 0;
opacity: 1;
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="keyword1" class="keyword">
<h3><a href="#phrase1">Keyword1</a></h3>
</div>
  
<div id="keyword2" class="keyword">
<h3><a href="#phrase2">Keyword2</a></h3>
</div>
  
<div id="keyword3" class="keyword">
<h3><a href="#phrase3">Keyword3</a></h3>
</div>
```

The random keyword appearing works fine, but the clearInterval function is not. I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like that way,

```
var intervalTime=0; 
$(function(){
  intervalTime = setInterval(generate, 4000);
})

$("[id*='keyword']").click(function() {
  clearInterval(intervalTime);
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I see what was needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

change two lines of your code like the following:

```
 window.intervalID = setInterval(generate, 4000);
```

and

```
clearInterval(window.intervalID);
```

Comment: I see that it needs and ID. Thank you!